# Impossible to write a simple ~ tilde while using bash in codecademy

Tags: bash, command, special-characters

i have a problem with the bash in Codecademy command line.
i'm a french speaker so my ~(tilde) is the same button as é, but i have a weird problem with that command; when i use alt + 2 it should make normaly a (~)tilde, but when i make it it gave me a 'é'... and while i do it twice it gave me that exact input 'éé~' is litteraly impossible for me to juste make a simple ~(tilde).

The weirdes thing is this problem is only valid for bash in CodeCademy and i have this problem since 2 days now.

somebody have an explication for that ?

Comment: It's not `Alt` but `Alt-Gr` that you have to use

Comment: i know it actually work everywhere, but it does not work with bash of codecademy